# Extend Nuxt 3 Config - Add alias for import paths

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vite, tsconfig

I use `nuxt 3.2.0` with `Vite`. In the Nuxt config (i.e. `nuxt.config.ts`) of a Nuxt 3 project, if you want to add a path alias, you can add it to the `alias` property ([see docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config/#alias)).

I added an alias for the components directory:

```js
// ...
alias: {
  '@/*': './components/*'
},
// ...
```

It got added to the `.nuxt/tsconfig.json`:

```json
"@/*": [
  "./components/*"
],
```

If I try to import something using that alias, there is no intellisense error, and I can ctrl-click on the path and get to the file.

```js
import { some } from '@/Something/something';
```

But the compiler breaks and there is a 500 error with `"Vite Error"`, `[[vite-node] [ERR_LOAD_URL]:`, I also got `Failed to load url /Something/something`.

So that path didn't include the alias.

If I change it to relative path , it worked:

```js
import { some } from './something';
```

I don't know if I might have missed something?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure but think you mixed up a few things. Tried to edit/correct your answer because of that.

Your `nuxt.config.ts` has to look like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    alias: {
        "@Components": "./components",
    }
})
```

To be enable the following import statement accros your codebase:

```js
import { some } from '@Components/something';
```

I think the root of your problem lies within the usage of `/*` in your config.

The tsconfig gets autogenerated by Nuxt as you pointed out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Galivan You might not need the custom configuration you had done. When looking at the code for the default config in Nuxt3 concerning `alias`, there are a few helpful defaults already configured.

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/main/packages/schema/src/config/common.ts#L309

- Both `@` and `~` bring you to the root of the `srcDir`
- If you want to start your reference from the root, you can use `@@` or `~~`.

> Note: If you use Webpack then images and CSS imports *has* to be referenced using the tilde (~). https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/main/packages/schema/src/config/common.ts#L309

Because I use a `components` folder I have the following in my Nuxt config:

```
components: [
  {
    path: "~/components",
    pathPrefix: false,
  },
],
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#components

If you wanted to set up an alias for your components directory, I believe it should look something like this:

```
alias: {
  'components': fileURLToPath(new URL('./components', import.meta.url)),
}
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#alias